# Neomake hanging when using eslint

Tags: neovim, quickfix, plugin-neomake

I have been following the following two tutorials to try and set up `eslint` and `Neomake`:

- [Linting code with Neomake and Neovim](https://www.gregjs.com/vim/2015/linting-code-with-neomake-and-neovim/)
- [Linting code with Neovim and Neomake - ESLint edition](https://www.gregjs.com/vim/2015/linting-code-with-neovim-and-neomake-eslint-edition/)

So I have the following minimal `init.vim`

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'neomake/neomake'

call plug#end()

autocmd! BufWritePost,BufEnter * Neomake
let g:neomake_verbose=3
let g:neomake_open_list = 2
let g:neomake_javascript_enabled_makers = ['eslint']

" neomake
nmap <Leader><Space>o :lopen<CR>      " open location window
nmap <Leader><Space>c :lclose<CR>     " close location window
nmap <Leader><Space>, :ll<CR>         " go to current error/warning
nmap <Leader><Space>n :lnext<CR>      " next error/warning
nmap <Leader><Space>p :lprev<CR>      " previous error/warning
```

The problem is when I save `Neomake` hangs with the following message:

`Neomake: Starting: eslint -f compact /home/otis/Developer/test/index.js`

If i run that command manually outside of `nvim` like so:

`eslint -f compact /home/otis/Developer/test/index.js`

I receive the following output:

```
/home/otis/Developer/test/index.js: line 1, col 1, Error - Unexpected var, use let or const instead. (no-var)
/home/otis/Developer/test/index.js: line 1, col 5, Error - 'a' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)
/home/otis/Developer/test/index.js: line 1, col 9, Error - Strings must use singlequote. (quotes)

3 problems
```

Which is good it means `eslint` is working but I am getting nothing back from `Neomake`.

If I run `:lopen` the window pops up and then instantly closes like below:

[image: Window open then close]

My `vim`/`nvim` knowledge is somewhat basic so please be explicit in responses.

Comment: try to change your `autocmd! BufWritePost,BufEnter * Neomake` to
`augroup neomake/
  au!/
  autocmd BufWritePost * Neomake/
augroup END`

BufEnter don't have many sense

Comment: Actually this might be the reason for empty Quick fix window. On your screen cast when you run `:lopen` Neomake runs for that buffer due to autocmd for BufEnter. @Yonsy snippet is good, but should be additionally limited to JavaScript files only: `augroup neomake/ au!/ autocmd BufWritePost *.js Neomake/ augroup END`

Answer (score 1):

Some [lightly edited] info from the comments:

> Actually this might be the reason for empty Quickfix window. On your screen cast when you run `:lopen`, Neomake runs for that buffer due to the autocmd for BufEnter. It should be additionally limited to JavaScript files only:

```
augroup neomake
  au!
  autocmd BufWritePost *.js Neomake
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I found that neomake works better with [eslint_d](https://github.com/mantoni/eslint_d.js). It has the nice side effect that it should do the linting faster too.

You first have to install eslint_d globally (but it still seems to pick up any local `.eslintrc` file):

```bash
npm install -g eslint_d
```

Then add the following configuration for neomake to your `init.vim` / `.vimrc`:

```
let g:neomake_javascript_enabled_makers = ['eslint_d']
```

For me that was all I required, after restarting neovim and opening a javascript file running `:Neomake` gave me eslint warnings.